# Azure Frontdoor Classic rules engine configuration to Premium

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I have to migrate an azure Front door classic configuration to Premium sku profile, however there are some differents between this two versions.
This is my rule engine configuration on Classic:
[image: Classic Rule engine configuration]

And this is my rule engine configuration on Premium:
[image]

How should I complete this form to have the same configuration on my Premium Profile?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For migration from classic to premium would sugggest you to please reach out to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/plans/) Reuqest or you can also follow this [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/training-services/microsoft-community-training/infrastructure-management/configure-your-platform-infrastructure/azure-front-door-migration) there is mentioned a email of MSFT , you can reach out to sangam-pm@microsoft.com for any concern related to migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   ***Switching between tiers or migrating between two different SKUs is not supported until now in Azure Front Door***, thus you will have to recreate the profiles accordingly as per the below documentation: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/tier-comparison#feature-comparison-between-tiers**

Also, do note that ***zero downtime migrations from Azure Front Door (Classic) to Azure Front Door (Premium) is in the roadmap for new feature improvement according to Microsoft***. Thus, as you are trying to reconfigure the rule configuration in Azure Front Door (Premium) profile likewise that in Standard, I would suggest you refer the below snapshots for your understanding: -

Azure Front Door (Classic) rule configuration: -

[image: AFD Classic ruleset]

Azure Front Door (Premium) rule configuration: -

[image: AFD Premium ruleset]

•   In the above screenshot, you want to *configure route type as ‘Forward’ to the backend pool for ‘HTTPS’ requests as well as enable the URL rewrite in ‘Classic’ profile of Azure Front Door*. To configure the **similar rule in ‘Premium’ profile of Azure Front Door**, please find the **above** screenshot. In that, to perform the similar functions accordingly, I have **set the ‘Override origin group’ to ‘Yes’ which implies that the configuration specified in the Front Door endpoint route will be overrided by this rule set condition** and will be **forwarded to the origin group that you specify/select in the origin group**. Along with it, since **you have enabled the URL rewrite to be enabled in ‘Classic’ profile, you will have the privilege of mentioning the detailed ‘Source’ and ‘Destination’ path rewrites in ‘Premium’ profile of Azure Front Door**.

Thus, **‘Premium’** profile of the Azure Front Door has ***more granular features*** compared to **‘Classic’** one and in this way, you can recreate the rule set in it. Also, find the below documentation link for more detailed understanding: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-rules-engine-actions?pivots=front-door-standard-premium&tabs=portal#RouteConfigurationOverride**